# Get post count of current loop when using multiple queries on one page

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm trying to get a count of the current posts inside of a loop. I'm using multiple loops on one page in my theme. So far I have:

```
$my_post_count = $wp_query->post_count;
```

But when I print $my_post_count, it returns the number all of the posts on my WP site. Could it have something to do with using multiple queries on one page? I tried using wp_reset_query after every loop to make sure I wasn't throwing things off that way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`$wp_query` hold main loop of page and should not be used to create multiple loops.

If you are using new `WP_Query` object then your variable that holds it will have according count:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();
// stuff
$count = $my_query->post_count;
```

If you are using `get_posts()` then `WP_Query` object is not accessible and you should just count returned set:

```
$posts = get_posts();
$count = count($posts);
```

Comment: Note: If you are in the main loop, you can access `WP_Query` through `global $wp_query`

Answer (score 6):

I believe the post_count is stored in the global, so before the custom loop you should set it to `0`, since you can use it outside the loop, but this depends on how you are structuring your multiple query's, maybe you can add them to your post?

There is another way that I use within the loop that counts posts using `current_post + 1`, for example.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query();?>
     <?php if ($my_query->have_posts()) :while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

           $count_posts = $my_query->current_post + 1; //counts posts in loop

     endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution using WP_Query would be:

```
           <?php 
               $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'post'
               );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $totalpost = $the_query->found_posts; 
            ?>
```

Comment: This is better if you are using pagination and want the complete total of all pages.

Comment: `found_posts` is better if you are using pagination and want the complete total of all pages.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to count total post including pagignation

```
<?php  global $wp_query
   echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
```

Comment: `found_posts` is better if you are using pagination and want the complete total of all pages.